# Service worker caching with workbox and server-side rendered SPA

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, service-worker, server-side-rendering, workbox

I have a server-side rendered react app and I want to add service worker caching to it.

In the app users can login and see their saved settings. On initial load the server serves the app with these settings pre-rendered based on auth cookie. If user is not logged in then server pre-renders login form instead.

If I use default cache-first strategy on the homepage index.html , then when user logs out and refreshes page, they will see the cached version where they were still logged in.

Using network-first strategy on index.html solves this problem partially, but it fails in this scenario: user logs out or changes any of their settings , goes offline and then refreshes the page - they would see cached version as if none of their actions ever happened, although they just saw the actual up to date version before refresh.

One solution I can think of is to update index.html cache each time a non-GET request happens - logout would have to be a DELETE request, for example. This would solve everything actually and might be universal enough to be included in the framework.

Anyway, I guess I can figure out how to listen to non-GET requests with workbox , but how can I update index.html cache in the listener?

I'll continue inspecting workbox source code, but I would love to get a hint, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it with an extra `fetch` listener working together with Workbox precaching: https://github.com/vfeskov/cra-ssr/commit/d269f55e9f9c83cb6a67033499c51f5a778bdb4a

I also wrote a detailed post about it: https://vfeskov.com/2017/12/29/Create-React-App-with-SSR-and-Service-Worker/

It's working on my pet project here: https://beer.vfeskov.com , try visiting, doing stuff, going offline and refreshing - it will always serve the last state the website was in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cache Storage API directly to [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage/delete) cached data when a user logs out. I'd recommend an approach where you use named caches in your Workbox strategies, and have a specific name (like `'user-data'`) for all of the data that's tied to a logged-in user. Then you can delete it via

```
// This code can run in the context of your web page:
if ('caches' in window) {
  window.caches.delete('user-data');
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that if you use a different cache name for data that's not specific to a given user (like, a cache of images or CSS files) you don't have to remove those cached entries when the user logs out.

Comment: thanks @jeff, I ended up writing an extra 'fetch' listener: https://github.com/vfeskov/win-a-beer-react/blob/master/client/src/service-worker.js#L10 , do you think such a behavior can be supported by workbox?

Comment: I think the main thing is that this doesn't need to be implemented inside of a service worker. You can access the Cache Storage API from the context of your web page, and when the user takes an action on your site (like clicking a "Logout" button, or whatnot) that requires clearing out data, you can clear out the caches as part of the same function that handles logging out.

Comment: For me clearing cache is not enough, because I want to cover case when you logout, go offline and then refresh page. Cache should be refreshed instead of just being removed to support this, and refreshing cache doesn't seem to belong to browser's main thread, what do you think?

Comment: Either approach would work. The caching operations are all asynchronous, and while they aren't "free", they shouldn't block your main JavaScript thread if you were to do them from the context of the web page. (We don't have any plans to add in "clear out an entire named cache" helpers to Workbox, since using the Cache Storage API directly handles this use case.)

Comment: Thanks @jeff, personally i like that all cache/sw-related stuff is in one place and the client app is unaware of any of that stuff, except registering the service worker, but you're right that it might as well be part of the client app. While this conversation was happening i refactored my version multiple times and it now looks super simple and works like a charm: https://github.com/vfeskov/win-a-beer-react/blob/b9a12d5994db3c0cb94b95c27df8333e6a67fa65/client/src/service-worker.js , would love to hear any suggestions